# Как вывести данные из POST запроса в Node.js в другую переменную?

Tags: javascript, node.js, post

Столкнулся с проблемой. На один URL сделал POST запрос через библиотеку request в node.js получил данные внутри самого блока, но не могу вывести эту переменную вне зоны видимости этого блока или определить в отдельную переменную:

```
const request = require('request')
request.post({url: "MY_URL"}, (err, httpResponse, body) => {
    var bodyData = body;
    console.log(bodyData);
});

console.log(bodyData);
```

Вывод в консоль:

> ReferenceError: bodyData is not defined

Подскажите, как решить. Буду благодарен.

Comment: Консоль пишет, что bodyData не определилась, следовательно body не был получен. Попробуйте для начала законсолить ошибку и посмотреть во вкладку network, что отправляете.

Comment: Сама bodyData в запросе выводится. А вне кода нет.
var bodyData = body;
    console.log(bodyData);
Этот код внутри блока выводит результат. А внешний
console.log(bodyData);
нет.

Comment: А, я не так понял, тогда вам нужно вызвать внешний метод и передать в него bodyData, подробности можете почитать по теме области видимости переменных.

Comment: Поискал. Все равно не нашел. Выдаёт undefined при любом более менее работающем коде.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не понятно, что вы имеете ввиду под "более менее работающий код", но из того что я понял, вы хотите:

```
    const request = require('request')
    request.post({url: "MY_URL"}, (err, httpResponse, body) => {
      var bodyData = body;
      console.log(bodyData); // здесь консоль лог видит данные

      somethingMethod(bodyData) // внутри функции мы видим глобально объявленную функцию и передаем в нее дату
    });

    console.log(bodyData); // здесь консоль лог данных не видит, так как для него переменная bodyData не определена (читаем про области видимости)

    function somethingMethod(data) { // принимаем дату и выводим ее в консоли
      console.log(data)
    }
```

Comment: Да. И мне надо использовать дату как отдельную переменную.

Comment: @RIXIN если вам нужно просто вынести дату в глобальную область, без дальнейшего использования в методе (не знаю зачем), то вы можете определить глобальную переменную рядом с константой request, например "let bodyData" и в пост запросе задать ей значение "bodyData = body"

Comment: Вы все правильно поняли. Сделал как вы сказали и выдается undefined.

Comment: @RIXIN кажется вы не понимаете еще одной фундаментальной вещи, такой как асинхронность. Допустим, вы сделали как я написал под ответом, вы объявили переменную bodyData со значением undefined, далее вы записываете в нее body в post запросе, но пытаетесь законсолить эту переменную вы раньше, чем происходит запись контента в нее. Т.е порядок сейчас такой: объявлена переменная > запуск консоль лога > запрос выполнился и переменная записалась. Потому я в ответе и написал, что нужно передавать body в метод, который вызовется тогда, когда body уже будет готов.

Comment: То есть то, что выше работает, но я просто раньше вызываю эту переменную?

Comment: @RIXIN то что написано у вас, не работает в любом случае. То, что я написал в ответе, работает. То, что я написал под ответом, работает, только если вы каким то образом дождетесь записи в переменную и только после этого к ней обратитесь.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо.)